# Insert Multiple Image into mysql db in phalcon

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

I'm want to insert multiple image into mysql database in separate column. i can print all image name but unable to separate the images name in a variable for insert into column. i'm inserting multiple image in single submit so when i try to insert image 1,2,3,4 print_r shows: "1.jpg2.jpg3.jpg4.jpg". How could i separate each *.jpg file in separate variable?

[FORM]

```
<input type="file" name="product_image[]" value="" multiple="multiple" />
```

[CONTROLLER]

```
        $insert = new Products();

        if(is_array($this->request->getUploadedFiles())){
            $image = $this->request->getUploadedFiles();
            foreach($image as $file)
            {
                $file->moveTo('uploads/shop/' . $file->getName());
                $myvars[] = $file->getName();
            }

            $insert->product_image1 = $myvars[0]);
            $insert->product_image2 = $myvars[1]);
            $insert->product_image3 = $myvars[2]);
            $insert->product_image4 = $myvars[3]);
            $insert->product_image5 = $myvars[4]);
            $insert->save();
        }
```

Comment: The reason you see `1.jpg2.jpg3.jpg4.jpg` is because you do a `print_r` on it. The loop is running, `$file->getName()` does what it is supposed to do. If you want to add these images in a different variable you can assign them to an array variable as a new element for each iteration. `$myvars[] = $file->getName()`

Comment: Plz Give a working example!! i just show short code which is main part. dont understand how to pass $myvars to db cause $myvars have multiple item

Comment: i update my code as u told but geting error : Notice: Array to string conversion in

Comment: `echo` does not work on an array (`$myvars`). This is why you get the error.

Comment: Adding the files in the database is a simple add. Create your model if you don't have it, set the property/field with the relevant data from the uploaded file and call `save()`  `$x = new Model(); $x->name = $file->getName(); $x->save();`

Comment: I know save method but not understanding that i have 5 field in db and  how "$file->getname();" know the targeted field for each image thats it.. plz ans asap plz

Comment: This is really a PHP/MySQL question not a Phalcon related one. If you have 5 fields: `field_1`, `field_2`, `field_3`, `field_4`, `field_5` and you need to store 5 images that came from the upload process then you can store them based on the array index of each element that comes from the `getUploadedFiles()`. You will not need a loop to gather your data. You can if you want to of course, then you create a 5 element array and then using that array you store each element in a field.

Comment: I updated my code plz tell me is it ok or not?

Comment: That should work. Reminder php arrays start from `0` not `1` so you have to adjust the numbers.

Comment: Yeap! its working but is it the best way ? or have any other short better solution then my code...? plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function insertAction()
{
    $insert = new Products();

    if($this->request->hasFiles(true) == true)
    {
        $image = $this->request->getUploadedFiles();
        foreach($image as $file)
        {
            if($this->imageCheck($file->getRealType()))
            {
                $file->moveTo('uploads/shop/' . $file->getName());

                $image = new Imagick('uploads/shop/' . $file->getName());   
                #Resize & Crop Image
                if($image->getWidth() >= 501 || $image->getHeight() >= 501)
                {                        
                    $image->resize(500,500);
                    $image->crop(500,500,0,0);
                }   
                $image->text('FireFly', TRUE, TRUE, 100, '#ddd', 30, ''); 
                $image->render(NULL, 60); 
                $image->sharpen(10);
                $imgName = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)).strtolower(date('-dmy-').$file->getName());
                $image->save($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/shopping/public/uploads/shop/'.$imgName);
                unlink('uploads/shop/' . $file->getName());                        
            }
            else
            {
                $this->flashSession->error("ERROR:: File extension not allowed");
                return $this->response->redirect($this->router->getControllerName());                    
            }   
            #Get Image Array() into a variable                 
            $myvars[] = $imgName;
        }
            $insert->pimg_front = empty($myvars[0]) ? "empty.png" : $myvars[0];
            $insert->pimg_back = empty($myvars[1]) ? "empty.png" : $myvars[1];
            $insert->pimg_top = empty($myvars[2]) ? "empty.png" : $myvars[2];
            $insert->pimg_left = empty($myvars[3]) ? "empty.png" : $myvars[3];
            $insert->pimg_right = empty($myvars[4]) ? "empty.png" : $myvars[4];
            $insert->pimg_bottom = empty($myvars[5]) ? "empty.png" : $myvars[5];
    }
    else{
            $insert->pimg_front = 'empty.png';
            $insert->pimg_back = 'empty.png';
            $insert->pimg_top = 'empty.png';
            $insert->pimg_left = 'empty.png';
            $insert->pimg_right = 'empty.png';
            $insert->pimg_bottom = 'empty.png';            
    }


    if($insert->save() == true){
        print_r('OK');
    }else{
       print_r('NO');
    }
}
```